Incorrect Axis Rotation in SCNTransaction
When modifying the sceneView.pointOfView?.transform property using SCNTransaction, if there's rotation involved, the axis of rotation is far from the 3D model, resulting in a sensation similar to that of a 'fly' mode being applied to it. How can we ensure it utilizes its own axis?

What I want:


To achieve the effect shown in the second image, you can just rotate the iPhone model right? Why are you changing the 'sceneView.pointOfView?.transform'

@codetiger Because this is not the only goal. The main objective is to create an animation from one point of view to another using SCNTransaction by changing the value of sceneView.pointOfView?.transform. Everything is good, except that the axis of rotation, as I mentioned, is not set correctly.

Plz share how you are configuring your scene. The issue has something to do with Where the camera is pointing and the position and pivot transform of the model.
